# Can you give me a hand understanding why my PHP array is throwing errors?

Tags: php

My code:

```
 <?php
 $myArray = ("Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob");
  print_r ($myArray);
?>
```

Is throwing the following error:

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "," in your code on line 4$myArray = ("Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob");

(It wasn't working when I uploaded the index.php file on my website so I used https://phpcodechecker.com/  to see what was wrong. )

Comment: This is not how you create an array in PHP.

Comment: why do you think that SO is better than official doc like https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ?

Answer (score 2):

You should change it to

```
$myArray=array("Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob");
```

or

```
$myArray=["Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use array(....) to assign elements to an array

Change the line

```
$myArray = ("Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob");
```

to

```
$myArray = array("Emily", "Meg", "Mary", "Bob");
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I knew it would be a rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

this is a syntax error you have to make the variable an array when you want to print multiple values in the array format the syntax would be something like

```
$variable_name = ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4");
```

to display values simply write like this -

```
print_r($variable_name);
```

Hope this answer will be helpful for you.